# Jenkins CI- Distributed Testing After a Build is done

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, jenkins, distributed

Currently this is I am trying to achieve: I use Jenkins to continuously build my project, I also want to do distributed testing after the builds are done, ie. dispatching smoke tests across multiple nodes/slaves, so that tests could get executed on multiple platforms simultaneously, each node would continuously accept newly dispatched test suite from the master server until all test suites are finished.

I tried:

- Setting up Master/Slave configuration on Jenkins
- Invoke Maven during build steps to run the Junit unit tests

However Jenkins would only select one slave to execute all tests.
I also tried DistTest plugin, but I found the plugin has trouble to set up relative path to libraries, does anyone has experience with this plugin?

So far the best way I came up with is:

- Create new Jenkins job for each slave available, and assign(hardcode) test suites on the slave
- use Multijob plugin to trigger all the job at once

This solution solves the problem, but it will be very difficult to scale once slaves increase to significant amount. I understand that Jenkins' main strength is on continuous integration rather than distributed testing, any advice on the tools or direction I should go into in order to realize this with Jenkins would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I read through what you want to achieve couple of times and what I understood / assume is that you have set of test suites you want to execute via a salve after the build is done either on a slave / master. Now I assume the type of testing and the associated Test suites are going to remain the same (like smoke test on one or more type of slaves (linux, MAc, Win, Solaris etc  and then you have other test suites like headless etc.) ..

Are these not going to be finite number of combinations to which you can create jobs and schedule them from within the master job to be executed in sequence, there is a [build flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) or [template workflow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Workflows+Plugin) or some infomration about [distributed builds in jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds).

Or If i need better control over the execution, I can just create an ant script that executes targets on multiple servers through remote command like [sshexec ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) and then have the flow orchestrated in the ant script.
The Ant script can be generalized to accept parameters which might be something like the dynamic values you are referring to.

Am curious to know where this goes for yourself. !!

Comment: +1 to your links. -0.5 for mentioning _ant_ and _better control_ and _remote command_ in a thread tagged _maven_ and _jenkins_. ;-)

Comment: Ha ha .. lol .. i love maven a lot and am sorry to have not mentioned that ... yes I am with you @geri .. maven is an easier tool to use and you can create profiles targeting different platforms and use them to configure your test suites too ..i was just sharing wat I do in my current application environment

Answer (score 0):

Are your JUnit smoke tests separate Maven projects?

If yes:

- create a Jenkins Maven project for each test
- use the [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) to label your slaves
- assign appropriate labels to your jobs

Jenkins distributes your builds automagically then.

That's how we do it for integration tests for a dozen of modules.

If your tests are not separate projects consider adapting them acccordingly.

---

@C.X.Yang: Commented on Oct 21 at 2:00 (CEST) here due to comment field length limit:

Is *"test set"* the same as *"test suite"* in your question?

We have a folder named `test` in every first-level project of our application. Each of these folders contains a [Multi-module POM](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects) containing (a large number of) tests as <modules>.

So, in the end we have just 15 Jenkins jobs that perform all tests and these 15 tests (+its sub-tests) are distributed across nodes via labels. We do not test on different platforms but I think that doesn't matter in principle - a node is a node.

Is there no common denominator in your tests so that you can assign/collect them to/in a limited number of appropriate Multi-module POMs?

About how many different platforms (does *platform* equal *OS*?) and test suites/sets are we talking at your site?

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I understood correctly, what you mean is to assign each job to a separate test sets, and use label to dispatch these sets automatically. What if I have a very large amount of test sets? Creating and configuring a new job for each set would be somewhat tedious.